# summing counts in sqlserver records based on similarly named column names

Tags: sql-server

In SQL server I'm trying to write a query that sums records together that have a similar name in another column, then also still show the records to non-summed records.

```
Route  TransactionType  Count

     F43   555A          100
     F43   345A          200
     F43   543A          75
     F43   765A          125
```

Instead of

```
Route  TransactionType  Count
 F43   555A-44          35
 F43   555A-42          25
 F43   555A-47          22
 F43   555A-45          18  
 F43   345A             200
 F43   543A             75
 F43   765A             125
```

The Attemped Query Example:

```
Select Route, TransactionType, Sum(Count) as Sum from
(
Select Route, TransactionType,Count(TrackID) as Count, from TheTable

)A
```

Comment: and if you google that error message..what do you get? It means you are missing a "GROUP BY" statement...

Comment: already fixed the error , sorry about that. Now I Just need to have it do my initial question.

Comment: fix your code in the question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a GROUP BY on the Transaction type.

```
   SELECT   
    ROUTE,
    SUBSTRING(TransactionType, 1, 4) ,
    SUM(TrackID)
FROM    TheTable
GROUP BY  ROUTE,SUBSTRING(TransactionType, 1, 4)
```

Comment: When you say groupname in the group by for transactiontype, do you mean you call it transaction type?

Comment: Sorry! Yes its transaction type.Edited my answer.

Comment: worked thank you. I never would have thought of this.

Answer (score 0):

If by similar name you mean that it has '-' sign in there, then this could be it.
Sample data:

```
SELECT 'F43' AS Route, '555A-44' AS TransactionType, 35 AS Count
INTO #Temporary
UNION ALL
SELECT 'F43' AS Route, '555A-42' AS TransactionType, 25 AS Count
UNION ALL
SELECT 'F43' AS Route, '555A-47' AS TransactionType, 22 AS Count
UNION ALL
SELECT 'F43' AS Route, '555A-45' AS TransactionType, 18 AS Count
UNION ALL
SELECT 'F43' AS Route, '345A' AS TransactionType, 200 AS Count
UNION ALL
SELECT 'F43' AS Route, '543A' AS TransactionType, 75 AS Count
UNION ALL
SELECT 'F43' AS Route, '765A' AS TransactionType, 125 AS Count
```

Actual query. I used CROSS APPLY just to make code look cleaner:

```
SELECT T.Route, F.FormattedRoute, SUM(Count) AS TotalCount
FROM #Temporary AS T
CROSS APPLY (SELECT IIF(CHARINDEX('-', T.TransactionType) = 0, T.TransactionType, LEFT(TransactionType, CHARINDEX('-', TransactionType) - 1))) AS F(FormattedRoute)
GROUP BY T.Route, F.FormattedRoute
```